# JSON Encode converts to null - so weird

Tags: javascript, php, json

This is the weirdest thing i've seen. I have an array that I created with php - then I used JSON_Encode to use it with a FLOT Graph. I echoed out the encoded array once - and it's perfect.

Then randomly, another alert box appears with "null".

Subsequently, the script also has a "null" when i echo it into the javascript.

the var d1 is null when I inspect it...

At first I get an alert box with `[[0,50],[1,3],[2,488],[3,25],[4,90],[5,50],[6,90],[7,50],[8,5]]` -- then I get a second alert box WHICH I DID NOT CODE with "null".

code:

```
<?php 
    $num = 0;
    while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        $line[] = array($num,intval($row->percent));
        $num ++;
    }
    $TEST = json_encode($line);
    echo "<script>alert('".$TEST."');</script>";
?>

<script>
    var d1 = <?php echo $TEST;?>;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.plot($("#chart"), [d1]);
    });
</script>
```

Output from Inspector:

```
var d1 = []; //Notice the empty array

$(document).ready(function () {
$.plot($("#chart"), [d1]);
});
```

Comment: Please show the code in a complete but as minimal as possible html file. I.e. something we could cut paste to replicate the issue.

Comment: It's all there. Nothing missing other than the includes for FLOT GRAPH... the problem is the output of the array is "[]"

Comment: I mean can you show it in form so I can paste into a file, render it with a browser and replicate the behavior given I have the FLOT libs?

Comment: It seems this is some kind of javascript problem... when I reload the section - it works for some reason. I use loadURL to refresh the div with the graph and when I activate it ... it works..

Comment: Did you test this code in a single page or inside your whole code? because this small part works fine.

Comment: Show us the part of your query too. The problem might originate there. The empty box might come from a query that yields no rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$line = array();` for empty data from while loop

```
$line = array();
while(....
```

You can check empty

```
if(count($line)!=0) {
    $TEST = json_encode($line);
    echo "<script>alert('".$TEST."');</script>";
}
```

UPDATE:

```
$TEST = json_encode($line);
echo "<script>$.plot($('#chart'), \"<?php echo $TEST; ?>\");</script>";
```

Comment: now it does the first alert box with the right data .. then a second one with "[]"

Comment: See but the problem is that it starts off full with data .. and for no reason converts to empty ... or i guess Reverts to the empty state.

Comment: I implemented that code and now instead of "[]" nothing happens - so instead of an empty array - it's now nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately still nothing.

Comment: For the last update `<script>
    var d1 = <?php echo $TEST;?>;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.plot($("#chart"), [d1]);
    });
</script>` code need to remove

Comment: Yes, I did :( still nothing.

Comment: Your code echoed out fine .. but the $TEST still turns up a []

Comment: Another try using double quote around PHP `var d1 = "<?php echo $TEST; ?>" ;`

Comment: OK Breakthrough! -- This is the weirdest thing - this graph is on a loadURL function, when I reload it - everything works ... how do I make it work the first time...